# Gantt Charts colour individual cells based on variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, gantt-chart

Has anyone used plexityhide's GTP.NET for asp.net 3.5 as I am trying to colour the individual cells based on a variable that I am getting from a linq query as follows:

```
PilotDataContext pilot = new PilotDataContext();

var schedule = from x in pilot.slot_tbl_Schedules select x;

foreach (var s in schedule)
{
    if (s.AppointmentType == "Repair")
    {
        CellLayout cl = gn.GetCell(0).Layout.Clone() as CellLayout;
        gn.GetCell(0).Layout = cll;
        cl.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
        cl.SelectedColor = Color.Red; 
    }
    else if (s.AppointmentType == "Service")
    {
        CellLayout cl = gn.GetCell(0).Layout.Clone() as CellLayout;
        gn.GetCell(0).Layout = cl;
        cl.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
    }
    else if (s.AppointmentType == "TravelTime")
    {
        CellLayout cl = gn.GetCell(0).Layout.Clone() as CellLayout;
        gn.GetCell(0).Layout = cl;
        cl.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
    }
    else if (s.AppointmentType == "AnnualLeave")
    {
        CellLayout cl = gn.GetCell(0).Layout.Clone() as CellLayout;
        gn.GetCell(0).Layout = cl;
        cl.BackgroundColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

The syntax in the if statement is what they have recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the CellLayout.BackgroundUse=true. If you don't the Background color is ignored.

And since you use ASP.NET the cellLayouts will generate a css, so you must add the new cloned CellLayouts to the collection on CellLayouts:

Gantt_ASP.Gantt.Grid.CellLayouts.Add(cl);

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cl2 As CellLayout = TryCast(e.GridNode.GetCell(4).Layout.Clone(), CellLayout)

cl2.SelectedColor = Color.Red
cl2.FontColor = Color.Red
cl2.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue
cl2.BackgroundUse = True ' when is true background color change 
e.GridNode.GetCell(4).Layout = cl2
```

it's working fine.....:)